# An unusual calculation of our universe's age?

Tags: cosmology, time, universe

Does the following make sense?  And has anyone else come
across this odd ~’cosmological coincidence’ before?…

…If we posit that our total universe mass is:
(1)     $$M_{U}=\frac{{M_{pl}}^4}{{M_{p}}^2M_{e}},$$
where $Mpl$, $Mp$ and $Me$ are the Planck, proton and electron masses
respectively, yielding a total mass of ~8.79x10^52 kg, this is close
to current notions of its mass, roughly ~10^53 kg.  We can assume
that our de Sitter universe is at critical density, where:
(2)     $$\rho_{c}=\frac{3H_o^2}{8{\pi}G}=\frac{M_U}{V_U}=\frac{3M_U}{4{\pi}{R_{U}}^3}.$$
Letting Ho ~ c / Ru, results in the well known criterion:
(3)     $$R_U=\frac{2GM_U}{c^2}.$$
This allows finding time elapsed, which approximates the ‘age of our
universe’, by using eq. (1), dividing by speed of light c, and
noting that Mpl=(hbar*c/G)^.5 , ie:
(4)     $$t_U=\frac{2G}{c^2}*\frac{\hbar^2c^2}{G^2}*\frac{1}{{M_p}^2Me}=\frac{2\hbar^2}{G{M_p}^2M_ec}.$$
Putting in the NIST values for the far right hand side, gives a
~“universe age” of 4.3618..x10^17 seconds or ~13.822 billion years.

This value is close to the final 2018 Planck Probe value of $t_u$,
“13.787 +/- 0.020” billion years and is well inside the error bars of
many of Planck’s other measured values of $t_u$.
This is very weird and striking…

If you’ve read this far, it can’t have escaped your notice that
eqs. (1) and (4) involve what are regarded as fundamental
constants.  Which IS problematical.  There have been ongoing
searches for changes in such parameters (excluding c, which
must be constant).  I note that claimed cosmic time changes
in $G$, $\hbar$, $Mp$ and $Me$ are disputed and not very convincing.

For what it’s worth, I found another way to derive eq. (4), using
binary orbits, where the proton and electron are in circular,
gravitational orbit around their common center of gravity.
NB: The only force involved is gravitational.  The only other
condition is that the proton’s orbital angular momentum
is hbar.  Ie:

(5)   $$\frac{GM_pM_e}{R^2}=\frac{\mu\,{v_p}^2}{R}\,\,and\,\,\hbar=M_pr_pv_p\,,$$

where mu is the reduced mass, MpMe/(Mp+Me), vp is the proton’s
orbital velocity, & R is the distance between proton and electron,
= rp + re, the radii sum of the proton and electron orbits respectively.
Letting vp^2 = hbar^2 / (Mp^2 rp^2) and simplifying a lot, and
solving for the diameter of the proton’s orbit, yields eq. (4) again:

ie:   $$t_U=\frac{2\hbar^2}{G{M_p}^2M_ec}.$$

To put it baldly, how legal is this?  And how it might connect with real
physics down in the basement of the universe is very opaque to me.
Quite probably a meaningless coincidence.  Which the history of
science is checkered with.

Comment: Personal theories and non-mainstream physics are off-topic on this site.

Comment: Eddington enjoyed playing with stuff like this, but it's essentially just numerology.  https://xkcd.com/1047/